How do I override the default Blazor T4 scaffolding template in Visual Studio 2022
I want to edit the scaffolding template for Blazor CRUD pages, but my changes to the template are not being reflected in the output.
I tried researching this issue, and the closest answers I could find are how to edit Razor templates, or MVC component templates. I tried following these instructions, adapting to my project (I copied the Blazor folder (C:\Users\username.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\8.0.2\Templates\Blazor) instead of Razor into a folder in my project called Templates, hierarchy shown here) and then I changed the header of the Create.tt file ( to MudBlazor's header text) to test if it would work:
<PageTitle>Create</PageTitle>
<!-- Test override -->
<MudText Typo="Typo.h3" GutterBottom="true">Create was changed</MudText>
<!-- Test override -->
<h4><#= modelName #></h4>
<hr />

but I noticed upon saving, a file named Create.cs would be created in the same folder with the only contents being
ErrorGeneratingOutput

and attempting to scaffold would give an error. I tried deleting the Create.cs file, and starting again, but it seemed like it used the default template instead of my override. I then changed the template inside the installation directory(C:\Users\username.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.web.codegenerators.mvc\8.0.2\Templates\Blazor), and tried scaffolding again, but again, no changes were shown in the output. What am I doing wrong?
Not sure if this is at all relevant, but Visual studio is spitting out these errors since I copied the template into my project.
